# Partial derivative of $\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$

Tags: calculus

Let's say we have $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}&(x,y) \neq (0,0)\\0&(x,y) = (0,0)\end{cases}$$

Using the definition of the partial derivative of $x$ in $(0,0)$, I get
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{h^2 0}{h^4+0}-0}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h^5} = \infty$$

But this should be $0$, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\frac{h^2\cdot 0}{h^4+0}=0$, not $\frac{1}{h^4}$.

Comment: You're right... the numerator is 0 anyway. Well, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noticed in the comments, we have that $\forall x,\,f(x,0)=0$ therefore

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\overbrace{\color{red}{\frac{h^2 0}{h^4+0}}}^{=0}-0}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{0}{h} =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}0= 0$$